# How to know user identity cookie is updated in ASP identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

When a user updates their user name or anything with regard to their User Identity, I re-login the user to refresh the user Identity cookie.

So how would I know if a user's cookie is not updated, for example, if the user had already opened their account on two browsers; one before updating and the other after updating?

Comment: What happens when you refresh the page on "before updating" browser?

Comment: @Legends the old user identity is being returned

Comment: You have to keep track of all sessions belonging to a user and if the user changes his profile data, i.e. username, then you could kill all sessions which belong to that user, in order to force a re-login. But  I wouldn't recommend this. Perhaps the user is filling out a large HTML form, then submits the page and gets logged out... this would be a bit annoying.